# Did I do it right? Deleting images after deleting product. Woocommerce

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic

I create, update and delete products using Woocommerce RestAPI, specifically this method:

```
$woocommerce->post('products/batch', $data);
```

After this method connected images remain in the server and db.

So, this is the code which deletes connected images from the database and server folder after deleting the post (product):

```
$this->woocommerce->post('products/batch', $data);
$this->deleteImages($data['delete']); // [ $key => $id_post ]

private function deleteImages($productIds)
    {
        foreach ( $productIds as $productId ) {
            $args = [
                //'numberposts' => 2,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'post_parent' => (int) $productId,
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
            ];
            $child = get_children($args);

            foreach ($child as $id => $item) {
                $pathImg = str_replace(get_site_url(), ABSPATH, $item->guid);
                $pathParts = pathinfo($pathImg);
                $extension =  end(explode(".", $pathImg));
                $imgWithoutExtension = $pathParts['dirname'] . '/' . basename($pathParts['basename'], '.' . $extension);

                array_map('unlink', glob($imgWithoutExtension . '*')); //ex:[img.jpg, img1x1.jpg, img5x5.jpg, img.gif]
                wp_delete_post($id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it normal realization? How would you edit this code?

Comment: featured image ids are stored in post meta not post parent column of posts table.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at @obmerks answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997698/delete-images-after-post you can simplify it with this:

```
foreach ( $productIds as $productId ) {
  $child_atts = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_parent = $productId AND post_type = 'attachment'");
  foreach ( $child_atts as $id ) wp_delete_attachment($id,true);
}
```

Note: as per documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment set the second parameter to true to force delete the attachment, otherwise it goes to trash.

Comment: `wp_delete_attachment($id,true)` deletes files from server?

Comment: Yes, and also auto-generated thumbnails. Remember to use "true" for second parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I just reinvented the weel. But without connection to DB, it looks better. Just `$child_atts = get_children($args)`

Comment: My pleasure :-)